# Page transition with framer motion in next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm building a web site with the following structure, I want to have some kind of slide in transition from the home page (.app/page.js) and every other page located in ./app/(content) because I have a total different layout for those pages. Is it possible? I've tried somethings but I think I'm doing it wrong because yes, I can do the slide transition, but for some reason the page just pops out and the next one do the slide animation, when it should slide over it.
Sorry if I can't explain myself, but if you can give me a hand I will really appreciate it.

[image: folder structure]

Comment: hey, am stuck on the same problem, did you figure it out?

Comment: Can you produce a reproducible code sandbox or stackblitz. I kinda have a vague idea of what you're trying to achieve but can;t really code it out right now. Maybe a simple "use client" could fix